# Event Handler seems to be correct but doesn't get thrown

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I am doing a Windows 8.1 phone app and I have a listview bound to the result of a query. Here is the xaml code for my listview and the method that fills the data. I'm trying to do something when the user clicks on the item but I inserted a breakpoint and nothing ever hits it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
private void lstStocks_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        stocksMainPivot.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

var query2 = from c in localSettings.Containers[query.FirstOrDefault()].Containers
                         select c.Key;

            if (query2.Count() > 0)
            {
                lstStocks.ItemsSource = query2;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this code to your ListView in XAML:

```
IsItemClickEnabled="True"
```

Because the default value is **False**, You must set it **True**. So your ListView Items can be Clicked.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't see something so simple. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If it works, please mark it as answer. So more people can get it correct.@user3610374